# how to get phone contacts in windows phone app 8.0 without using silverlight template

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I  am new to windows developement. I want to get the  contacts from phone, but i am getting contacts from phone when i am using silverlight template. Now i want  without using sliverlight template i need to get contacts from phone. i tried  alot,but i failed to get the contacts from phone without using silverlight template. please any one help me how to get the cotacts from phone without using silver light template.I am using Blankapp(windows phone) template in visual studio 2013

thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post some example code that isn't working properly. It would help people identify where you might be going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at [How to access contact data for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh286416(v=vs.105).aspx) and [Selecting user contacts Windows Phone Store app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn631246.aspx). First link is refering to Silverlight app, the second one - Windows Runtime